# R for loop to loop through subdirectories to read SAS txt and Setup files and bind in a dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, sas

I have a directory (dir2 in the code below) with 200 subdirectory folders, each of which contains a `.txt` data file and a `Setup.sas` file. I need to write a for loop that uses the `asciiSetupReader` package to loop over each subdirectory, read the files therein using the `sas_ascii_reader` function and row-bind all the resulting read objects to one data frame. I know this must be relatively simple but am having difficulties.

I have generated a dataframe that has two columns: one of the list of file names of the `.txt` files and another of the list of accompanying `Setup.sas` files.

```
list_file_txt <- list.files(path = './dir1/dir2', 
                        pattern='*Data.txt', 
                        recursive=TRUE)

list_file_sas <- list.files(path = './dir1/dir2', 
                        pattern='*Setup.sas', 
                        recursive=TRUE)

files <- as.data.frame(cbind(list_file_txt,list_file_sas))

files <- files %>% 
  mutate(directory = str_sub(list_file_txt,1,7), 
         directory = paste0('/dir1/dir2/',directory))
```

I have attempted:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(files)) { 
  setwd(files$directory)
  sas_ascii_reader(dataset_name = '*Data.txt',
                   sas_name = '*Setup.sas', 
                   real_names = FALSE)
  }
```

Results in error,

```
Error in setwd(files$directory) : cannot change working directory
```

which I understand indicates that R is not recognizing the character strings in the files$directory column as file paths to reference.

I have also tried (as referenced at [How to import files from subdirectories and name them with subdirectory name R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49831148/how-to-import-files-from-subdirectories-and-name-them-with-subdirectory-name-r))

```
library(tidyverse)
tbl <-
  list.files(path = './dir1/dir2', 
             recursive=TRUE) %>% 
  map_dfr(sas_ascii_reader, 
          dataset_name = '*Data.txt',
          sas_name = '*Setup.sas', 
          .id = "filepath")
```

but get

```
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : is.logical(value_label_fix) is not TRUE
```

which I don't understand at all.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks all.

Comment: First problem: you should use `list.files(full.names = TRUE)`. Otherwise `list.files` will simply return the file names without their directories, which `setwd` won't be able to find. Second problem: try `setwd(files$directory[i])'. Currently you are passing the entire vector of directories.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations @jdobres. I now get ```Error in setwd(files$directory[i]) : cannot change working directory```. I'm working within an RStudio project space. Would that affect my ability to leverage setwd?